# Thoughts on this 3-way wiring job

Tags: electrical, switch, light, multiway-switch

Greetings from Australia

I'm in the process of putting Z-wave nano dimmers behind my 240v light switches and up to wiring an interesting 3-way switch config backing 3x LED drivers.

This is what I found when I popped the plates off...

---

Switches:

[image]

---

Can anyone pick out how this has actually been wired and why they would go about doing it this way?

I'm going to check this out further tomorrow but thought I'd drop it in here to get some opinions.

---

Looks like active is at COM of Switch #1 and those T1/T2 are definitely the travelers

[image]

I now have enough info to wire my Z-wave Nano switch. Thanks to everyone for their input!

Comment: What country are you located in?

Comment: I am located in Australia

Comment: Au black-neutral red-hot white-spare

Comment: Is the wire behind the wall in a box, or a cavity? The first picture blacks should be wound tighter before inserting under a screw. I do not know if it is acceptable to have > 1 wire under a screw on a switch like this but even if it is, where you have 3 looks tight, or like it should be tighter - did someone cut strands off to shove them in the hole? Also, while none of these are glaringly a problem, they should be dressed better and clean when inserted. excess copper showing outside of where it is needed is sloppy.

Comment: thanks for the comments guys. @noybman no box in wall - seems to be common in australia. i'm definitely going to be cleaning it up as way too exposed for my liking. I'm assuming the t1/t2 terminals are corresponding on either switches given that white wire but do you think the common terminal on "switch 1" are going back to the active terminal on the LED drivers? I'm not sure why there's all those black/neutrals looped at "switch 1" either...

Comment: Can we have photos that show which wire is going to which cable?

Comment: Photos have been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oz wiring looks kinda weird to folk in the top half of the planet.

This seems to be an Oz equivalent of what Brits would call 2-way switches and what Americans would call 3-way switches

[image]

The "loop" connector is presumably not wired to the switch but is a provided as a convenience to save having a floating connector-block (or wire-nut).

In your case it looks like the three blacks shown at right in the diagram above have, in your photo, been connected using a "loop" terminal rather than by using a floating connector block.

It isn't clear from your photos if the rest of the your wiring's connections are consistent with this diagram.

It might be that the triple reds and triple blacks in your first photo are where some parallel (separately switched) lights branch off.

Comment: Is there a limit on the # and size of wire that can be screwed into the switch plate? I mean, where he has 3, is it appropriate.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I've updated the photos and testing the wires right now! :)

Comment: I've updated the photos with my tests. I'm rewarding this answer as it's the closest to what they have done.